# Is is possibel to get the area from a polyline on the viewer using Forge Viewer API?

Tags: autocad, polyline, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I wanted to find the area enclosed by a closed polyline in the Forge JS viewer API. I am able to find the length in the properties but not the area, since area is available in the properties in Autocad, I think there must be some way to get it from the properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see this property for **POLYLINES** in other **AutoCAD** drawings?
Did you check if you can see the property in e.g. **A360**? It seems to be there in case of my drawing, so it should be available inside the **Viewer** as well:

[image]

Comment: `On A360 : http://imgur.com/XVuO3dt`
`On Viewer : http://imgur.com/FmMofJJ`

Comment: Can you help me with the reason as to why this isn't visible to me, can tell me on what version of autocad was the drawing made. I used autocad 2015 for Mac.

Comment: I think I tested with an AutoCAD 2017 drawing on Windows. 
"why this isn't visible to me" - you mean you cannot see that property in A360 either?

Comment: Yes, the only properties I see are the ones I sent in the screenshot.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a non-confidential DWG file that could be used to reproduce the issue? Then I could log it with engineering. Thank you.

Comment: [link1](https://mega.nz/#!vRVmxbTS!oTJarojn9XzsuzMq4Nr_x2nugF9SozwZPWaJqgaKXSE) .  [link2](https://mega.nz/#!mUdFCDqT!YYeixlRqK72aK52dKf3tCwqnIegLSKLHcFsgCn4QwOc)

Comment: Thank you for the files. I could reproduce the behaviour, but it's not clear why those properties are not available in case of your drawing. I logged this issue in our system and I hope it will be looked at soon. Issue id: TREX-556 Sorry for the inconvenience :(

Comment: Thanks.Can you also post the link for the issue id - would be easier for me to track it as well.

Comment: That's an internal id - so no public link to it -, but you can ask for an update on it from us. I'll also try to keep an eye on it and will post here an update on it if I hear anything.

Comment: Can you provide me the drawing with polyline whose screenshot you have uploaded in the answer. So I can can consider is a benchmark until the bug is fixed?

Comment: Turns out the difference is not in the drawings, but when they got translated, as the translation service changed. I was asked what properties you would need. Is it only the "Area" that you really miss?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: What is the number of vertices that your polylines might have? Do you have a number for that? Like, is it definitely below 100? Asking because area calculation during extraction for huge polylines can be really slow (compared to other things), and that's the reason  why that was taken out. :-/

Comment: Yes definitely below 100

Comment: Can we get update on jira issue TREX-556 regarding area extraction.

Comment: Still trying to find out when the issue will be fixed. Will provide an update here as soon as I know more.

Comment: [Aman Kaushal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3502851/aman-kaushal) and [alpheus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020290/alpheus), would you mind contacting me directly on adam.nagy@autodesk.com to discuss the workflows you need this for? Thanks

Comment: @alpheus we are working on bringing back those properties. Hopefully that will be done within the next couple of weeks.